# How to get the first word in a line Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the first word in a line (e.g. apple, book, chair). I have a long list of French words and their meanings in English:

```
French,English
partie,part
histoire,history
chercher,search
seulement,only
police,police
...
```

This list is stored in a csv. I want to get a random French word from this list. Does anybody know how I can do this?

My code(currently):

```
import random
with open('data/french_words.csv', 'r') as french_words:
    french_words_list = french_words.readlines()
rand_french_word = random.choice(french_words_list)
```

Comment: P.S. The list of French and English words is way longer, I just didn't want to take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```py
import random

with open("words.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip one line (i.e., the header)
    words = [line.split(',')[0] for line in f]

random_word = random.choice(words)
print(random_word) # histoire
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the csv into a DataFrame if the list is big

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('french_words.csv')
df['French'].sample()
```